# Firefox reload page loop debugging hints?

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

One of my javascript heavy pages reloads itself endlessly when using a deep link in firefox. (I'm using jquery address plugin btw.)

The page works fine in Chrome and IE, but not in FF. I have tried debugging it using firebug, but the problem is that when the page reloads firebug is reset.

Any hints on how I could debug this *besides stepping the code and adding log statements*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could set Firebug to *persist* the console so you can see errors on reload.

[image: Firebug]